# accidentally set chrome so it never asks me whether I prefer chrome or stack exchange app. how do I fix this?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have an android phone and use chrome. I have the stack exchange app. But I happened to be googling and went to the stack exchange via chrome. A pop up came up that asked me whether I would prefer to use chrome or the stack exchange app whenever I click on a stack exchange link.

Unfortunately, I accidentally set it so that it always chooses chrome. Really, I would prefer to be asked each time. Is there a way to reset this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Go into Settings
2. Navigate to the Apps menu
3. Browse all apps
4. Find the application you want to remove as the default (Chrome in your case)
5. Hit "Clear defaults"

[Source](http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-change-default-apps-in-android)